# return specific item from a laravel collection and remove it

Tags: php, laravel, closures

im trying to map over a collection of query results. Specifically i want to check if an item of that collection suits my closure, returns that item and removes it from that collection. Further more i need to pass parameters with the closure function.

```
$data = Model::where('something', 'stuff')->get();
$res = array();
foreach ($x as $y) {
  $res = $data->each("closure function described above with $y");
  // do stuff with $res
}
```

i hope this was clear 
thank You for Your help 
cheers.

Comment: Looks like this one: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pull

Answer (score 3):

You may try something like following, assumed you have some data in `$variables` and `$y=general` as a `type`, so check if the `type` is `general` then do something with the model that has type `general` and then put that model in the `$res` array and then remove it from the collection:

```
$variables = '...';
$res = array();
$y = 'general'; // for example, $y contains general
$data = Model::where('something', 'stuff')->get();
foreach ($variables as $variable) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $model) {
        if($model->type == $y) {
            // Do something with $model
            $res[] = $model;
            unset($data[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Also you may check [this article](http://heera.it/extend-laravel-eloquent-collection-object#.U05pSvmSySo), it maybe helpful to interact with a `Collection` object.

Comment: I had my code, just like you proposed here, but i wanted to make it simpler/shorter and somehow use a method from the collection object itself. Btw, instead of unset() you can use forget($key) on the collection object. I will read the article you posted, thank you!

Comment: I used `unset` because it's faster than `forget` and this is better to use native `PHP` wrapper function.

Comment: This answer, `unset($data[$key]);`, is how I usually do it.

Comment: Sorry @Salkz, didn't get what you asked for.

Comment: @TheAlpha I was just agreeing with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To use a variable inside your closure you have to use the keyword 'use' ;).

```
function($item) use ($y) {
    // remove item from collection by key 
    //using collection.forget($key) 
}
```

Comment: Yes, but if I keep the closure function in a different class, how will i pass the '$y' on to it?

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question. I don't know if that is even possible. You could try to define the closure in your class with use and test whether it takes the current available y in the context or not

Comment: sorry for not being specific, would it be easier to define my function in the Collection class and use it directly on the $data object? or is that bad practice? thank you

Comment: I always write my closures where I need them (in your case inside the each) . That's why it's a closure. In another case it's just a normal passed function.

Answer (score 0):

With laravel 5 you can use where method on collection.

```
$data = Model::where('something', 'stuff')->get();

$removedItem = $data->where('key', 'value');
```

Or if you use Larave 4 you can call filter method on collection

```
$removedItem = $data->filter(function($item) use ($removedValue) {
    return $item->key == $removedValue;
});

$data = $data->diff($removedItem);
```